# Hilbert Basis Theorem for Artinian Ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Does there exist an analog of the Hilbert Basis Theorem for Artinian Rings?

$$R ... \text{Artinian} \rightarrow R[X] ... \text{Artinian}$$

This question came up in whether the prime spectrum $\text{Spec} (A)$ of a ring $A$ is artinian as a Zariski Topological space when $A$ is artinian.

**Partial Answer: (Wrong per Ross P)**

For a ring $R$ (commutative with unit), Noetherian is equivalent to Artinian. This is proven [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143028/artinian-if-and-only-if-noetherian?rq=1). Hence, $\text{Spec}(A)$ is Noetherian *and* Artinian if $A$ is a field.

Answer (score 5):

The partial answer you state is not true.  The answer in that post is for modules over $R$ satisfying certain properties on some maximal ideal $m\lhd R$.  Certainly for commutative rings $R$ is Artinian if and only if $R$ is Noetherian **and has Krull dimension 0**.  Also for a field $K$ and finite type $K$-algebra $R$ it can be shown that dim$(R)$ is the transcendence degree of $R$ over $K$.  (see, for instance, Atiyah-MacDonald 'Introduction to Commutative Algebra')

We can use these facts to note that a field $K$ is Artinian, but $K[x]$ has dimension 1, so cannot possibly be Artinian.  A fundamental boundary to your proposed statement.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $R$ is not the zero ring.  Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $R$.  Then $\mathfrak{p}[x]$, the ideal of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathfrak{p}$, is a prime ideal of $R[x]$.  But $(\mathfrak{p}[x], x)$ is a prime ideal properly containing $\mathfrak{p}[x]$ so we see that $\dim(R[x]) > \dim(R) \ge 0$.  So $\dim R[x]$ is always at least $1$ and **$R[x]$ is never ever Artinian** (unless $R$ is the zero ring).

Comment: To nitpick, your argument assumes that $R$ has a prime ideal.  In fact, if $R$ is the zero ring, then $R[x]$ is artinian since it is also the zero ring.

Comment: Yes that is a fair point! Updated